Why does opening a socket delay for a minute with IPv6 but not with IPv4?
On my Windows 10 desktop machine, I am running the following bit of Python (3.10.9) to make an HTTP POST request:
import json
import requests

response = requests.post(
    url="https://foo.bar/baz",
    headers={
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': "bazz",
    },
    data=json.dumps({"key":"value"})
)

When I ran the code in PyCharm, I found that the call to the post() method consistently stalls for about 63 seconds before returning. As this is an unreasonably long time to get a response from this API, I ran the same code in the same way on a different computer and found that the call returns almost immediately with a good response.
Having profiled the code in PyCharm, I can see that it's the call to Python socket.connect() method that causes the 63-seconds delay.
Following advice I've found online, I've disabled IPv6 on the Ethernet adapter that I use to access the internet:

Once I've done that, when I run the code, it returns immediately with no delay.
My question is - Why is this happening and how can I re-enable IPv6 on the Ethernet adapter and not experience the 63 second delay?

Additional observations:

The https://foo.bar API application seems to have both IPv6 addressed and IPv4 addresses:

❯❯ nslookup foo.bar

Server:  vulcan.local
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    foo.bar
Addresses:  2606:4700:20::****:****
          2606:4700:20::****:****
          2606:4700:20::****:****
          172.67.***.***
          104.26.***.***
          104.26.***.***


When enabled, the IPv6 feature is configured to have default values (as far as I can tell).





UPDATE : I can add that when I disable the Ethernet adapter and enable a wifi adapter that has IPv6 enabled (again with default properties), the delay disappears.
Pinging the domain with -6 does not work, I think because they've disabled ping on their end. However, nslookup -type=AAAA foo.bar yields a difference in the order in which the IPv6 addresses are listed.
Ethernet:
Addresses:  2606:4700:20::****:158
          2606:4700:20::****:48c5
          2606:4700:20::****:58
          172.67.***.***
          104.26.***.***
          104.26.***.***


Wifi:
Addresses:  2606:4700:20::****:48c5
          2606:4700:20::****:158
          2606:4700:20::****:58
          172.67.***.***
          104.26.***.***
          104.26.***.***

Is it possible that the first address for Ethernet is faulty and causes the delay? How can I prove this to the owner of the API? Or, can I manually control the order on my end?

Does the other computer have IPv6 enabled as well? More specifically, does it have IP addresses from the same prefixes, and does it use the same IPv6 default gateway? Can both machines ping -6 the server – and since it has more than one address, are all the addresses equally pingable? (And just to make sure, if you look at the IPv6 packets with Wireshark, are they being sent through the same Ethernet, to the same MAC address?)

It would appear you have IPv6 configured, but either you or the service you are trying to reach have it set up incorrectly.
